# rel="prev" и rel="next" добавить на главную вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Привет,

Кто подскажет как на главную страницу добавить `<link rel="prev" href="http://namesite.com/page/2" /> и <link rel="next" href="http://namesite.com/page/4" />`
Сайт на вордпрессе. Использую плагин Yoast SEO. Возможно есть какой-то хук.
На всех остальніх страницах, где есть пагинация все работает хорошо. Проблема только на главной.
Спасибо!

Comment: Напишите, как сейчас выводится на главной и на других страницах. И поясните, при чем тут Yoast SEO?

Comment: На главной вообще не выводится. Yoast SEO - это плагин который если есть пагинация выводит то что мне нужно. Как их удалить есть много инфы, а вот как их добавить нет.

Comment: https://yoast.com/rel-next-prev-paginated-archives/